# Cookies or Session and how to begin

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

Heey Stackoverflow,

I have an question im started to learn asp.net language csharp and i have the following login code my question is how to begin or where can i learn to write down the session cookie and than i can get back to the other page to read this cookie out again for the username and password that did match ty very much

```
public partial class Administratie : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Stefan"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Username],[Password] from Admin where [Username] = @Username and [Password] = @Password", con))
            {
                string Username = (textUsername.Text.Length > 0) ? textUsername.Text : null;
                string Password = (TextPassword.Text.Length > 0) ? TextPassword.Text : null;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textUsername.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextPassword.Text;

                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                        if (Page.IsValid)
                    {                     

                        // Login Succeed 
                        // Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");







                    }
                }
            }



        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        // Login Failed
        Response.Write("Wrong Username ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try look here:

[Create and retrieve Cookie data (C#)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Session-Cookie/CreateandretrieveCookiedataC.htm)

Read a Cookie:

```
  HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Preferences"];
  if (cookie == null)
  {
    lblWelcome.Text = "<b>Unknown Customer</b>";
  }
  else
  {
    lblWelcome.Text = "<b>Cookie Found.</b><br><br>";
    lblWelcome.Text += "Welcome, " + cookie["Name"];
  }
```

Set a Cookie

```
  HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Preferences"];
  if (cookie == null)
  {
    cookie = new HttpCookie("Preferences");
  }

  cookie["Name"] = txtName.Text;
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

If you want to store data in a Session just set it:

```
Session["username"]=username;
```

and read:

```
string username=Session["username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store username and password. If you want to use remember me option you can save the username and password in cookies.

Please check the links for using [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx) and [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)